# Add comment in SSIS expression

Tags: ssis

I am using "Expression Task" in SSIS.  I would like to add a comment in the expression.  What characters should I use?  For example:

1. Java uses // or /**/
2. VBA uses '
3. tsql uses -- or /**/

What can I use in SSIS expressions? (I tried all of the above)

Comment: I don't think so you can comment expressions..

Comment: You can add comments in the background though. Click a blank space in the control flow / work flow and start typing!

Comment: You can also [add annotations beside the expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139981.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

Annotations are unwieldy in documenting expressions buried within executables and only so much can be stored in an executable's 'Description' property but they are better than nothing and should be used where practical.

But when an on-the-spot comment is indespensible one can resort to trickery.
For example in a string expression:

"expression where "+"string is being built"+LEFT("Important comment",0)

Similar contrivances work in Boolean expressions by OR'ing something impossible such as:

@real==@comparison || "my comment"==""

Numeric expressions require a back flip but casting a comment to 1 or 0 lets you imbed it by adding zero or multiplying by 1 at some point in your formula.  For example:

@numeric*@factor*(DT_I1)LEFT( "1some comment", 1 )

I doubt anyone who as ever built an expression of complexity isn't frustrated by the fact that this basic functionality still doesn't exist.

Comment: great input on using the description property. that's what our team has settled on for comments on expressions

Comment: Likewise, a great timesaver when testing email recipient variables, can paste the original email in the description property, then paste in my test email, then back after testing.